# Unable to get <s:property> value as a parameter to java script function in the Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, displaytag

I am using DisplayTag table library with Struts2 for displaying records from database.I am able to get table data in display tag table. I wanted to pass one of the columns (Column name: Location name) value to javascript function via button on click. But I'm unable to get that property value. Below is code snippet of it.

```
<display:table class="table-responsive table-striped table" export="false"  id="requestListLocationInfo"  name="requestListLocationInfo"  requestURI="#" pagesize="50" >    
        <display:column title="Sl No.">
${requestListLocationInfo_rowNum}</display:column>
        <display:column property="location_name" title="Location Name" sortable="false" />
        <display:column property="status_loc" title="Status" sortable="false"   />
        <display:column property="created_by" title="Created By"  sortable="false"   />
        <display:column property="date_loc" title="Created Date"  sortable="false"   />
        <display:column title="Modify"><button onclick="getModifyDetails('<s:property value="location_name"/>')">Modify</button></display:column>
</display:table>
```

and javascript function is as shown below.

```
function getModifyDetails(location_name){
        alert('loc name is'+location_name);
        var url = "./getModifyLocDetails.action?location_name="+location_name;
        window.open(url,"_blank","directories=no, status=no,width=700, height=500,top=0,left=0");
    }
```

How do I get column value as parameter to js function?

Comment: Is the JS function in the same file? Are there characters in `location_name` that would break JS evaluation? (You should always escape things like this.) What's in the console? More importantly, what is *rendered*?

Comment: Yes, the JS function is in the same file. There are no special characters in location_name. There are no errors in Console, but got some warning message as mentioned.vendor.bundle.addons.js:21012 [Deprecation] The keyword 'caret' for -webkit-appearance CSS property is deprecated and will be removed in M75, around June 2019. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5075579829223424 for more details.
applyToTag @ vendor.bundle.addons.js:21012
addStyle @ vendor.bundle.addons.js:20994
addStylesToDom @ vendor.bundle.addons.js:20922
module.exports @ vendor.bundle.addons.js:21053
(anonymous)

Comment: And what is rendered?

Comment: <button onclick="getModifyDetails('')">Modify</button>   . I'm getting this when it rendered

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24530974/573032